# Il ne faut pas prendre les enfants du bon dieu pour des canards sauvages

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison

En parcourant la liste des vieux films de mon père, je suis tombé sur cette expression qui est aussi le titre d'un film comique de 1968. Comme je suis un peu curieux, j'ai cherché un peu et [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/il-ne-faut-pas-prendre-les-enfants-du-bon-dieu-pour-des-canards-sauvages.php) nous donne une possible piste de signification / traduction mais pas l'origine. Des idées ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je pense que cela vient tout simplement de l'imagination fertile de [Michel Audiard](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Audiard).

Comment: Le film d'Audiard est sorti en 1968, l'expression existait avant cette date.

Answer (score 8):

L'expression a été rendue populaire par le roman d'[Antoine Blondin](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Blondin) :  [*Les enfants du bon dieu*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Enfants_du_bon_Dieu) paru en 1952. Le héros du roman est un professeur d'histoire qui ne veut pas être pris pour un canard sauvage et « il ne faudrait pas prendre les enfants du bon dieu pour des canards sauvages » est dit dans le roman  par un élève excédé des remarques de l'inspecteur qui regarde son cahier. La phrase est aussi placée en [exergue du roman](http://books.google.fr/books?ei=hAhUU7exJ-LY7Aa444HoCg&hl=fr&id=LfPvAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22antoine%20blondin%22%20%22les%20enfants%20du%20bon%20dieu%20pour%20des%20canards%20sauvages%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%20%22les%20enfants%20du%20bon%20dieu%20pour%20des%20canards%20sauvages%22).

On ne sait pas si c'est Blondin qui a créé l'expression mais elle a souvent été reprise par la suite, notamment par [Michel Audiard](http://books.google.fr/books?id=TZcBAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT225&dq=%22antoine%20blondin%22%20%22les%20enfants%20du%20bon%20dieu%20pour%20des%20canards%20sauvages%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=hAhUU7exJ-LY7Aa444HoCg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22antoine%20blondin%22%20%22les%20enfants%20du%20bon%20dieu%20pour%20des%20canards%20sauvages%22&f=false), qui appréciait beaucoup Blondin et a adapté, à ma connaissance, au moins un de ses romans au cinéma (*Un singe en hiver*).